# Should the links in a REST API be placed in the response header or body?

Tags: json, rest, restful-url

Is there a best practice for where to put the links to other resources in a REST API response? When I look at standards like HAL they always seem to put their links in the body, is there a reason for that? I'm developing an API in JAX-RS so it would be really easy to the links in the header, so it would be great if that's a viable option

Answer (score 1):

If you have an actual Hypermedia content type, then, yes, the links should be in the body. Having the link type is part and parcel to what a Hypermedia data type is all about.

However, not all media type support hypermedia (for example, images), so any relevant links for those types can only belong in the header.

In the end, though, as you say, "it's really easy", then by all means, just use the header links.

You can also put them in both places. Use the header links for yourself in your system (i.e. you can assume they're there and leverage them), and if it's not a huge burden, populate the same links within the Hypermedia documents that you publish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would a client not be able to access these, or is it just not standard to look in the header for them?

Comment: That's a documentation problem. The reply is the reply, it's not like the headers won't be there. But perhaps for the client the payload links are easier for them to work with just like for you the header links are easier work with. The message doesn't care.

Comment: [Ketting](https://github.com/evert/ketting) doesn't care where the links are, so you can even move them later and this is not considered a BC break.